# testthat with lintr::expect_lint_free() fails with devtools::check() but works with devtools::test()

Tags: r, testthat, lintr

This test in my package works fine with `devtools::test()`. Also the online Travis build is going well.

```
test_that("Package style", {
  lintr::expect_lint_free()
})
```

However, with `devtools::check()` it fails.
The error message is

```
   invalid 'path' argument
     Backtrace:
      1. lintr::expect_lint_free()
      2. lintr::lint_package(...)
      3. base::normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE)
      4. base::path.expand(path)
```

I'm running R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29), testthat 2.3.2 and lintr 2.0.1 on Windows.

I think the problem is that lintr doesn't know which file(s) to lintr.

Could somebody please point out to me what the solution to this problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This is [known bug](https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/issues/421) with lintr. Currently, the best workaround for it is replacing your code with:

```r
if (requireNamespace("lintr", quietly = TRUE)) {
  library(lintr)

  context("linting package")
  test_that("Package Style", {

    # A duplicate copy of the find_package function from lintr
    find_package <- function(path) {
      path <- normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE)

      while (!file.exists(file.path(path, "DESCRIPTION"))) {
        path <- dirname(path)
        if (identical(path, dirname(path))) {
          return(NULL)
        }
      }

      path
    }

    if (!is.null(find_package("."))) {
      expect_lint_free()
      )
    }
  })
}
```

The source for this solution is in that [same link](https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/issues/421).